# json to .net class generator for wcf service

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, jira

I have JIRA json string like this:

```
[
{
    "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/project/EX",
    "id": "10000",
    "key": "EX",
    "name": "Example",
    "avatarUrls": {
        "48x48": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=large&pid=10000",
        "24x24": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10000",
        "16x16": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10000",
        "32x32": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10000"
    },
    "projectCategory": {
        "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/projectCategory/10000",
        "id": "10000",
        "name": "FIRST",
        "description": "First Project Category"
    }
},
{
    "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/project/ABC",
    "id": "10001",
    "key": "ABC",
    "name": "Alphabetical",
    "avatarUrls": {
        "48x48": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=large&pid=10001",
        "24x24": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=small&pid=10001",
        "16x16": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=xsmall&pid=10001",
        "32x32": "http://www.example.com/jira/secure/projectavatar?size=medium&pid=10001"
    },
    "projectCategory": {
        "self": "http://www.example.com/jira/rest/api/2/projectCategory/10000",
        "id": "10000",
        "name": "FIRST",
        "description": "First Project Category"
    }
}
]
```

Used this (http://jsonutils.com/) to convert this to .Net class. However, I want to use this class in my WCF service. Do I need to add data contact and data member to it?

I'm getting avatar url like below (this is few lines of code from my class):

```
 public class AvatarUrls
    {
    public string 48x48 { get; set; }
    public string 24x24 { get; set; }
    public string 16x16 { get; set; }
    public string 32x32 { get; set; }
   }
```

If I'm setting "Property Attributes" as data member. Its showing me result as:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class AvatarUrls
    {
        [DataMember(Name="48x48")]
        public string 48x48 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name="24x24")]
        public string 24x24 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name="16x16")]
        public string 16x16 { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name="32x32")]
        public string 32x32 { get; set; }
    }
```

The error I'm getting here are:
1.The type or namespace name "x48" could not be found(missing assemble reference)
2. string -> expected class, delegate,enum, interface or struct

Just wanted to know, Can I use like this in my WCF code? I'm bit confused, if its correct or not? What is wrong? am I missing something? please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`48x48` and the like are not valid identifiers, change them to something like `Icon_48x48` and use the DataMember attribute in the same way you already are.

Comment: Thank you so much. The error got removed now. By the way, what is this Avatar URL? why it is being used? Can not we just ignore that? Any  sample code example?

Comment: An avatar is a little icon to represent a user. If you don't care about the users picture then yes you can just ignore these.